# UIImagePickerController is throwing error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have following code to open the photo library or camera but whenever I run the code I get a runtime error:

```
WhatsUp[28458:10570522] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: _UIImagePickerControllerMediaTypes)'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Here is my code:

```
 // open the camera
        self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController(rootViewController: self)
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera

        } else {
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }

        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have already added the privacy keys to the info.plist file as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Change `UIImagePickerController(rootViewController: self)` to `UIImagePickerController()`.

Comment: Yup! that was it. Thanks! If you can post that as answer I can accept it. Also will appreciate one line reason of why change it (). Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the inherited `UINavigationController` initializer when creating your image picker. But the proper way is to use the initializer with no arguments.

The line:

```
self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController(rootViewController: self)
```

needs to be:

```
self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
```

By using the wrong initializer the image picker isn't setup correctly.